# Como poder meter html en un objeto javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que estoy haciendo es que en wordpress estoy creando un objeto con

```
post.push([

{
contenido: "<?php the_content(); ?>",
}
])
```

Pero cuando hago eso, the content me lo devuelve en HTML y javascript me lo marca como error.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que `push` debería admitir un json. Por lo tanto deberías escaparlo.

Podrías probar con:

```
post.push([
{
contenido: "<?php json_encode(the_content()); ?>",
}
])
```